# Converting string to an integer in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsinteger

I know this question has been asked many times. You can convert string to integer in this two ways:

`[myString intValue]` which returns a "C" type or `[myString integerValue]` which returns NSInteger.

But my requirement looks like this:

```
int route1 = 12,route2 = 5,route3 = 6;
for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        int route = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"route%i",j] integerValue];
        //do something using the route
}
```

I need the route variable to take the values of the different routes depending on the value of variable j.

How do i do it? Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Your question is a bit weird. Why do you need this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
int routes[3] = {12, 5, 6};
```

and in your for loop :

```
int route = routes[j];
```

No need to convert anything

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure what you are trying to do here. You should probably use a route integer array or something and reference the indexes. From what it looks like you are trying to get the values from `"route1",` `"route2"`, `"route3"`.

You should look at the use of `intValue` or `integerValue`. If you had an `NSString` who's value was `"1234"` it would return the integer `1234`.